# tomcatの猫の画面が表示されない (404)

Tags: linux, tomcat

## 環境

CentOS　5.11
tomcat6

## インストールの時の方法

```
# yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk
# yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel

# vi ~/.bashrc
```

(以下の内容を追加)

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64; export JAVA_HOME
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64; export JRE_HOME
```

```
# source ~/.bashrc

# yum install tomcat6 tomcat6-admin-webapps
# chown -R tomcat:tomcat /usr/share/tomcat6
# chown -R tomcat:tomcat /etc/tomcat6/*
```

## インストール後にやったこと

```
# vi /etc/tomcat6/web.xml 
文字コードをutf-8に変更

# service tomcat6 start
でサービススタート。
```

## 確認したこと

クライアントマシンからIEで「[http://ホスト名:8080](http://%E3%83%9B%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E5%90%8D:8080)」を確認。
404が返ってくる。

ポートが重複していないことも確認。

ログの確認
  /var/log/tomcat6/

- catalina.2016-04-11.log
- catalina.out
- host-manager.2016-04-11.log
- localhost.2016-04-11.log
- manager.2016-04-11.log

catalina.2016-04-11.logとcatalina.outには起動したときの情報が出ていたが、エラーはなし。すべてinfoレベル。
それ以外のログはなし。

## その他の情報

Apacheもインストールしてみたら「[http://ホスト名/](http://%E3%83%9B%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E5%90%8D/)」で普通にapacheの画面が表示された。

あまり関係ないが、tomcatの「[http://ホスト名:8080](http://%E3%83%9B%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E5%90%8D:8080)」はapacheが起動している状態、起動していない状態で両方試したが結果はやはり404。

## コメントをうけて追記

/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/の下には「host-manager」と「manager」という二つのディレクトリが存在しますが、それ以外は何もファイルは置かれていないですね。

こちらのページを参考にしたのですが、特に設定などなく普通はtomcatの猫の画像があるページが表示されるようです。
http://kajuhome.com/tomcat6.shtml

とはいえwebapps下に何もないので表示されないのは当たり前と言われればその通りなのですが。

上記参考URLの中で最低限必要なのはJAVA_HOMEの設定ぐらいかと思い、設定しましたがやはり404でした。

## 追記

下記のhello.jspを「/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/host-manager/」配下に置いて、ブラウザで「[http://ホスト名:8080/host-manager/hello.jsp](http://%E3%83%9B%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E5%90%8D:8080/host-manager/hello.jsp)」でアクセスしたところ正常にjavaコードが実行されてページが表示されました。

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=Shift_JIS" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<%
out.println(new java.util.Date());
%>

</body>
</html>
```

しかし上記ファイルを「/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/」に置いて、ブラウザで「[http://ホスト名:8080/hello.jsp](http://%E3%83%9B%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E5%90%8D:8080/hello.jsp)」にアクセスしても404になります。

ドキュメントルートの設定がおかしいのでしょうか？

ひとまずtomcatでJSPが動くことは確認したので、先に進めそうですが、なるべくなら猫のページが表示されない問題を理解して解決したいと思っています。
知識がある方がいましたらよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 404は、File Not Found(ファイルが無い）というエラーですが、フォルダwebappsの中に必要なファイルは置かれていますか？ Apacheは動作確認用のファイルが自動的にインストールされますが、tomcatは設定作業が必要なはずです。

Comment: Tomcatのルートパス直下にファイルを置く場合は webappsの下に/ROOT という特別なディレクトリへ保存します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おそらく、jpackage.org のリポジトリを利用しているのだと思います。
tomcat6-webapps をインストールする必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ご指摘の通りでした。
解決いたしました。